# excluding and repositioning of fields within Forms

Tags: django

I have excluded a field like this in order to set it's label.

```
class ContactsForm(ModelForm):
    marital_status    = forms.ModelChoiceField(label=_(u'Marital Status'), queryset=MaritalStatus.objects.all())

class Meta:
        model = Contact
        exclude = ('marital_status',)
```

This works, however marital status now appears at the very end of the form after all other elements.

Is there a way to specify the field's position?

**Alternatively** I didn't even have to exclude the field in first place, if I was able to set the label within the model it self, like the example below, where I set the label "Day of Birth".  I can't seem to be able to set the label for models.ForeignKey, any idea?

```
marital_status      = models.ForeignKey(MaritalStatus)
birth_date          = models.DateField(_(u"Day Of Birth"), blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'verbose_name' attribute while defining foreign key, which will be displayed as label in the form.

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names

```
marital_status = models.ForeignKey(MaritalStatus, verbose_name=_(u'Marital Status'))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to exclude it at all. Just declare it as you do in the first example and leave it out of the `exclude` param.

Comment: I wished I could tick off both answers as correct. This works as well, many thanks. I think its less legwork, if I used verbose_name though.